# express request - empty body in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, request

I am running an express server that is requesting data from an external API using the request module. For only some of the endpoints, however, I am receiving an empty response body. For example:

```js
request.get({
  url,
  headers: { [...] }
}, (err, response, body) => {
  // err === null
  // body === ''
});
```

The strange thing is, the exact same request returns proper data through curl or the Insomnia app.

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

A few other notes:

- all requests (working and not working) have the same base url, headers, and are being requested using the request module (the only difference being the endpoint)
- I'm using the body-parser module as such, though I'm not sure if it's relevant :

  ```
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));
  ```

Please help! I'm really scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: @KeKsBoTer I'm not sure, though I've only seen these issues in my dev environment, running on localhost

Comment: I ounce had problems with npm and my proxy settings. While curl and wget worked fine, npm could not do the proxy authentication right.

Comment: Show us the cURL request.